# What is a "moorland farmer"?

Tags: meaning, expressions, oxymoron

I came across the phrase "moorland farmer" yesterday while reading *The Hound of the Baskervilles*, and Google shows that the phrase has some currency. [[link](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22moorland+farmer%22)]

We don't have moors in the U.S. — or if we do then we don't call them that — so I'd previously looked up the term when I read *Jane Eyre*. Wikipedia is typical in its explanation that: "Moorland nowadays generally means uncultivated hill land (such as Dartmoor in South West England)". [[link](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Moorland)]

So "moorland farmer" puzzles me; it sounds like an oxymoron, since farming normally implies cultivation.

Is "moorland farmer" using "moorland" in a vague sense to encompass the whole region, even parts that actually are cultivated? Or does "moorland farmer" mean someone plowing previously unbroken soil — something like "pioneers" in American history? Or something else?

Comment: Maybe moorland is land that is not very fertile, which might require some adjustments.  Or maybe one grazes sheep on large tracts of it.

Comment: In the UK, the term "farming" encompasses both arable farming and livestock farming. It is possible to be a livestock farmer (e.g. a "sheep farmer") without performing any ploughing or other cultivation of plant crops. Of course, many farms are mixed and farmers may grow crops to feed their animals. Not all do. In (some parts of) the USA maybe that is called ranching instead of farming.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

A ***moorland farmer*** farms the ***moorland*!**

[image]

1. *[Moorland](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/moorland)* is a large region:

> noun
>
> [MASS NOUN] (also moorlands) chiefly British   An extensive area of
> *moor*:

And a *[moor](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/moor#moor__4)* is a specific kind of land:

> noun
>
> chiefly British 1 A tract of open uncultivated upland, typically
> covered with heather:

2. Although the connotations of *cultivating* and *farming* overlap significantly, the distinction between them applies to our understanding of the expression *moorland farmer*:

> *[cultivate](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/cultivate)*
>
> verb
>
> 1.0 [WITH OBJECT] Prepare and use (land) for crops or gardening:
>
> 1.1 Break up (soil) in preparation for sowing or planting: (as adjective, with submodifier cultivated)
>
> 1.2 Raise or grow (plants), especially on a large scale for commercial purposes:
>
> *[farming](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/farming)*
>
> noun
>
> [MASS NOUN] The activity or business of growing crops ***and raising
> livestock***:
>
> *ODO **Emphasis** mine*

Because the region is hilly and less fertile, the *moorland* is not easy to *cultivate*, but it is **wonderful** for pasture, which can be fed directly to grazing animals, like sheep, goats, cows and even horses.

[image]

Smaller tracts in the moorland are suitable for cultivation, being harvested for hay to feed the animals during winter, or even cultivated for gardens and cash crops--especially berry bushes and fruit trees, which demand less intensive soil preparation than other crops.

[image]

---

3. It seems the precise definition of *[moorland](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Moorland)* is shifting away from the historical meaning of *[moor](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?term=moor&allowed_in_frame=0)*:

> "waste ground," Old English mor "morass, swamp,"
> from Proto-Germanic
> *mora- (cognates: Old Saxon, Middle Dutch, Dutch meer "swamp," Old High
> German muor "swamp," also "sea," German Moor "moor," Old Norse
> mörr "moorland," marr "sea"),
> perhaps related to mere (n.), or from
> root *mer- "to die," hence "dead land."
> The basic sense in place names
> is 'marsh', a kind of low-lying wetland possibly regarded as less
> fertile than mersc 'marsh.' The development of the senses 'dry
> heathland, barren upland' is not fully accounted for but may be due to
> the idea of infertility. [Cambridge Dictionary of English Place-Names]
>
> etymonline.com

The low lying marshes, like *[Sedgemoor](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sedgemoor)*, were included in the archetypical *moorlands*, but are now designated as *[wetlands](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wetland#Technical_definitions)*. Although the high *moorlands* have been slowly transformed by centuries of hill farming methods, sections of the remaining *moorlands*, like *[Dartmoor National Park](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dartmoor)* are now protected from extensive cultivation:

> Dartmoor is an area of moorland in south Devon, England. Protected by
> National Park status as Dartmoor National Park, it covers 954 square
> kilometres (368 sq mi).[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zw7Vr.jpg)

[image]

---

4. *[The Hound of the Baskervilles](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Hound_of_the_Baskervilles)*, was written as a serial between 1901 and 1902. The adventure was set in the world-famous [Dartmoor in Devon](http://www.visitdevon.co.uk/areas-to-visit/dartmoor-national-park-west-devon/), and provides ample description of the territory, which includes hills, dales, villages, farms and bogs, including the "Great Grimpen Mire" which though fictional is inspired by the [Fox Tor Mires](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fox_Tor):

[image]

---

**Conclusion**.

Although the expression *moorland farmer* contains plenteous semantic confusion, it is not an oxymoron:

1. *Grazing* livestock, the primary farming activity of the moorland, is on the boundary of meaning for the word *cultivate*, but the word *farmer* is is applied more broadly.
2. The *moorland* regions do not contain homogenous soil profiles, so there is limited classical cultivation in the moorland regions, except where it has been prohibited by law.
3. The definition of *moor* has flipped diametrically since the 13th century, but some usages still reflect the ancient connotations.
4. *The Hound of the Baskervilles* seems to welcome a broad understanding of *moorland*, but the plot seems to emphasize a marshy *moor*.

Comment: There are [small moors, in central England](http://greensandtrust.org/FDHG/), that are lowland boggy areas. It is land that is uncultivatable but potentially usable for grazing cattle or sheep.

Comment: @RedGrittyBrick, before researching for this answer, I might have concurred in calling them moors, and no one could out right call it wrong, but modern experts seem to prefer a different name for the low wetlands.

Comment: The Ordnance Survey names them moors on their 1:25000 maps. It probably reflects long-standing local usage.

Comment: I wouldn't necessarily expect something named a "moor" to consist of "moorland".  Although the two are obviously linked, there are grazing areas that have been named a "moor" that bear little or no relation to what is understood by "moorland".  For example, the Town Moor in Newcastle-upon-Tyne, which is a 1000 acre expanse of grazing land adjoining the city centre.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. So if I'm understanding correctly, the reason "moorland farmer" is not an oxymoron is twofold: firstly, that "moorland" doesn't necessarily imply that it's absolutely 100% uncultivated, and secondly, that a "farmer" doesn't necessarily have to cultivate his/her land, if (s)he's using it to pasture livestock. Do I have that right?

Comment: The four good answers that have been presented seem to hover around that conclusion, @ruakh. See my conclusion edit.

Answer (score 10):

It is an traditions expression used to refer to farmers who usually rear sheep and cattle in the uplands. It is often referred to as **hill farming.**

> - Farming on moorlands brings its own rewards – and problems! The land is less fertile than in lowland areas and the weather can be harsh. **[Moorland farmers](http://www.cairngormsmoorlands.co.uk/moorland_farming.htm)** often have to adapt their farming methods and timings to take this into account.
>
>   - Lambing can begin later than on some lowland farms and good shepherding using dogs, quad bikes and land rovers is needed to manage the flocks properly.
>   - It is important to move the cattle around the moor during the summer to prevent over-grazing occurring in one area, and some form of shelter is required for the harsh winter months.
> - [Hill farming](http://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hill_farming)  is extensive farming in upland areas, primarily rearing sheep, although historically cattle were often reared extensively in upland areas. Fell farming is the farming of fells, a fell being an area of uncultivated high ground used as common grazing. It is a term commonly used in Northern England, especially in the Lake District and the Pennine Dales. Elsewhere, the terms hill farming or pastoral farming are more commonly used.

(Wikipedia)

There is no statutory definition of **‘[uplands](https://www.gov.uk/hill-farming)’,**

> - **but it is generally accepted to refer to areas of mountain, moor and heath, high ground above the upper limits of enclosed farmland, largely covered by dry and wet dwarf shrub heath species and rough grassland.** Hill farms also have adjacent land in the form of semi-improved and improved grassland that are used in conjunction with the moorland and rough grazing. All of this land needs to be sustainably managed in order to safeguard the valuable biodiversity of the plants and animals that can only thrive in these habitats.

(www.gov.uk/hill-farming)

Answer (score 7):

## Archetypal Moorland

> What are Moorlands ?
>
> Moorland is the name given to areas usually dominated by shrubs such as Bell Heather, Ling and Gorse or various rough grasses and sedges. On Exmoor Moorlands include upland heath type habitats **as well as the often wetter and more peaty mires**. They usually occur on the **poorer, peaty soils** on the higher parts of Exmoor.

My emphasis.

From [Exmoor National Park](http://www.exmoor-nationalpark.gov.uk/environment/moorland)

The largest and best known moorlands include Dartmoor, Exmoor, The North York moors and others. It is these upland moors that most people think of in connection with the word moor.

---

Footnote:

## Other types of Moor

As I mentioned in a comment to another answer. In other, more lowland parts of Britain, local names for peaty mires can include the word "moor".

As an example, the [Two moors heritage trail](http://greensandtrust.org/FDHG/) in Bedford passes through Flitwick moor, designated a site of special scientific interest (SSSI), nearby lies Flitton Moor and Black Moor Farm.

[image]

> The whole of the Flit Valley from Westoning to Shefford would have been largely **peat bog** 200 years ago and was dug for fuel turves as in the picture of **Flitton Moor** by Thomas Fisher

Thomas Fisher lived from 1782 to 1836.

Westoning to Shefford is about 8 miles (13 Km). Only tiny fragments of this habitat remain intact.

> the Old English mōr **also refers to low-lying wetlands** (such as Sedgemoor, also SW England).

From [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Moorland)

## Farming

> **Is "moorland farmer" using "moorland" ... to encompass  parts that actually are cultivated?**
>
> **Does "moorland farmer" mean someone plowing previously unbroken soil**

In Britain at least, not all farming implies cultivation and ploughing. Livestock farmers such as sheep or cattle farmers might not cultivate any crops or plough any fields.

Cultivating crops and ploughing is mainly performed by arable farmers, less so by livestock farmers.

Comment: +1 This is an excellent counterpoint that addresses the ambiguity within the expression *moorland*.

Comment: Thanks! The "Other types of Moor" section is not really relevant to my question -- *The Hound of the Baskervilles* takes place in the "uplands" type of moor -- but the "Farming" section at the end is very helpful. +1 :-)

Answer (score 0):

The answer is in the book itself.
In The Hound of the Baskervilles the moorland is **swamp** rather than hills.

Stapleton, a character from the book, describes the place as **mire**, here is a quotation from The Hound of the Baskervilles on [Google Books](https://books.google.com.ua/books?id=JuGobGYpH8cC&printsec=frontcover#v=onepage&q&f=false)

> "... You see, for example, this great plain to the north here, with the queer hills breaking out of it. Do you observe anything remarkable about that?"
>
> "It would be a rare place for a gallop."
>
> "You would naturally think so and the thought has cost several their lives before now. You notice those bright green spots scattered thickly over it?".
>
> Yes, they seem more fertile than the rest."
>
> Stampleton laughed. "That is the great Grimpen Mire," said he.
>
> "A false step yonder means death to man or beast.
>
> "It's gone!" said he. "The mire has him...."

So, '**moorland farmer**' is a **livestock farmer** or **sheep farmer** maybe, in this case, and all the dangers of the moorland in the book are associated with drowning in the mud.

Comment: I take it you haven't read the book? :-)

Comment: @ruakh - It was a spoiler :-). The book does not explain what the 'moorland farmer' is anyway, which is livestock owner.